# rebuilding solution fails but rebuilding projects one by one will succeed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, build

I have a solution in visual studio 2010 that consists of several windows applications. I added dll reference of one of this projects(called "A") in another project(called "B"). I also added reference of Automapper.dll in project "B".
problem is :
when I only rebuild project "B" it will build successfully, but when I rebuild all the solution , it will failed because Automapper.dll and A.dll aren't found. Meanwhile every time that I build the solution I should remove Automapper.dll and A.dll from project "B" and adding them again, otherwise building project B will faild.
I also clean the solution but it doesn't work still.
I'm waiting for your advices.
Thanks all...

Comment: Project B is Rcts.Proxy.Security.

Comment: No B is RCTS.Proxy.ServiceClient and A is RCTS.Proxy.SVCProxy

Comment: it builded successfully. a filke wrongly was moved to Security. I removed it. thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that project A is selected to build in current solution configuration (Build/Configuration Manager). Also, please check that you added B -> A reference as a project reference, not as dll reference.

It seems that B (Rcts.Proxy.Security) reference to the Automapper is broken. Make sure that automapper dll is located in some external folder, not in bin/obj, before adding a reference. Or rebuild will erase automapper.dll from bin, causing build to fail. Try using [Automapper nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper) to make sure reference is added correctly.

The first project that fails to build is Rcts.Proxy.Security. You should fix it's references first. It is missing a reference to  RCTS.Proxy.SVCProxy (or have a non-project reference). It is clear that VS attempts to build Rcts.Proxy.Security before RCTS.Proxy.SVCProxy and fails on missing RCTS.Proxy.SVCProxy class.

Comment: I check both of them. they were correct. but still i have the problem.

Comment: please attach a solution rebuild log

Comment: this is output history:

Comment: Excuse me it's too long, I'm try to attach it

Comment: unfortunately I can't edit my question, how can i send it to you?

Comment: paste it to the pastebin.com, I will edit a question to include build log.

Comment: dear Pashapash I add output history to my question, thank you